# How does Bless work?

Tags: disk-utility, startup, bless

I'm getting an SSD for my wife's MBP 2010. I was planning to install the old HDD and the new SSD into my MacPro and just use disk utility to copy all the info from her old disk to the new one. It would be easy enough and once the new disk is installed she can pick right up where she left off.

But I had an idea to reduce her downtime while the disks were copying. If I install the SSD into my MacPro first. then copy all the files over the network from her MBP onto the SSD. All I would need to do is bless the new SSD and I should be able to just swap the two drives and it should be perfectly bootable with all files and settings intact right? the MBP only needs to be down for the 15mins it takes me to change the drives.

I'm just a little bit confused about how Bless works though. It just lets the computers firmware know where to find the boot-loader right? but is that info saved in the firmware? or is it apart of whatever filesystem the Blessed files exist on? I guess what I'm asking is, if I bless the SSD while it's in my MacPro, will it mess up the MacPro's boot settings? and Not make the SSD bootable? Or will it work like I hope it does and just make the SSD bootable so that it can go into the MBP and just work? Or do I need to add extra options for that?

PS: yes I realize that this all just creates a bunch of extra work for me to save an hour (at most) of downtime on the laptop. But I had the idea and now I want to know.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't trust a network copy to successfully copy all of the relevant metadata (file permissions, etc) to make a fully working macOS system. What might go wrong depends on exactly how you do the copy. But Disk Utility's "Restore" feature *will* do a high-fidelity copy. I'd go with that.

Comment: I was thinking of using rsync with can verify transferred files as well is preserve permissions. But I get that just using Disk Utility is the best way to do it and that's how I will be doing it. But I wanted to know how Bless would work in that scenario providing I did everything else right.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think again about 'saving time'.

While you're cloning it - however you do it - the chances are high that the work actually been done at the same time won't get cloned. To ensure it does, you'd have to clone it again...

I'd just prepare for 2 hours downtime - or wait 'til bedtime - use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to clone the old drive to the new [that would probably be easier in the Mac Pro, just in terms of physical access, unless you have an external USB/SATA drive adaptor], then just swap them over.
It will boot & you'll be back to where you were 2 hours ago, but with a zippy new SSD. It will also make a new Recovery Partition on the new drive.

A little trick to make the swapover easier...
Before you clone the old drive & while not booted from it, rename the old drive to *whateverNameOld*, then make sure the new one is GUID/HFS+ & named *whateverName*.
Once the clone is finished & swapped back into the MBP, the OS won't waste any time at all trying to figure out where everything went.

Comment: great advice. that's likely what I'll end up doing. But doesn't touch on my actual question. Will Bless work if I run it on the new SSD from the MacPro? (assuming of course I have successfully copied ALL the files with permissions intact)

Comment: tbh, I don't know... however, ***if*** you get everything right, then just hold Opt at first boot & it will let you choose a bootable volume; or in fact if it doesn't know what to boot from, it will hunt until it finds one. To bless it after successful boot all you need to do is select it in Sys Prefs > Startup Disk & it will do it for you.

Comment: so you're saying that if I install the SSD unblessed. the MBP firmware will search through the entire filesystem looking for the boot.efi file? and if it finds that, it will allow me to boot from it?

Comment: The boot folder & boot.efi are always at specific inodes... though, in fact, turns out I was wrong about the blessing part; apparently that is separate from merely having the correct files in the correct places. (My excuse is I've only ever done this with CCC, never tried it any other way;) CCC has a far better explanation than I can muster - https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/what-makes-volume-bootablehttps://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/what-makes-volume-bootable